# Efficiently find all reachable nodes from every node

Tags: r, igraph

I have a non-directional edge list that looks something like the following (Except that it has hundreds of thousands of nodes and edges):

```
map <- list(1,1,1,2,6,5,2,3,4,7) %>% matrix(nrow = 5, ncol = 2)
```

I have been trying to find a way to separate this table into groups of nodes that can reach eachother.  In the above example, I would want to see the set `c(1,2,3,4,5)` and the set `c(6,7)` as distinct groups.

I've been working with different ideas and stumbled upon the `igraph` package which would let me use `graph_from_edgelist` to make an igrap object and then I can use `dfs` on each node it turn to find every node accessible to that node.  I even went so far as to rule out visited nodes so that I don't repeat things, but it's still very slow.

This i the best I've got, but I was hoping for something much faster.

```
graph <- graph_from_edgelist(map,firected = F)
all_nodes <- c(map[,1],map[,2]) %>% unlist() %>% unique()
visited <- c()
node_groups <- list()

for(i in 1:length(all_nodes)){
    if(!(i %in% visited)) {
        temp <- dfs(graph,i,neimode = "all", unreachable = F)[[3]]
        temp <- temp[!is.na(temp)]
        node_groups[[length(node_groups) + 1 ]] <- temp
        visited <- c(visited, temp)
    }
}
```

I'm hoping that I'm just overlooking an obvious function somewhere, or that there's a simple optimization technique that will let me keep doing my analysis in R.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you looked at the function `components`?

Comment: @G5W No, no I hadn't.  That's exactly what I was looking for.  I feel quite chagrined. Thank you!